Prevent tagging of inactive users in discussion comment mentions
In hosted ADO (dev.azure.com), our instance has users who are inactive, but can still be mentioned with @ in the discussion comments. Is there a way to limit the mention list to just active users?

You can try the following ways:

Delete the inactive users.

Delete the users from the Azure DevOps organization at first.
Then delete the users from the AAD (Microsoft Entra ID) that the organization is connected to.


If the inactive users still in the Azure DevOps organization or cannot be deleted, try to use the "Limit user visibility and collaboration to specific projects" preview feature.

Turn on the "Limit user visibility and collaboration to specific projects" preview feature for the Azure DevOps organization.


Add the users as the member of the Project-Scoped Users group.


Remove the access of the users from all the projects.





For more details, you also can see "Limited identities in search selection" and "Limit user visibility for projects and more".

EDIT:
If there are some wort items assigned to the inactive user, you can bulk assign the work items to an active user before deleting the inactive user. For more details, you can see "Bulk modify (web)".

Create a work item query to list all the work items assigned to the inactive user.

On the query Results section, Select all the listed work items and right click. On the pop-up menu list, select "Assigned to >" and then select an active user.





I think the problem is, that some work items are assigned to ex-employees. If I delete the users, what happens to the work items assigned to them? What happens to the discussion comments and History data?

@spikey_richie, You can bulk assign the work items to an active user before deleting the inactive user. See EDIT in my answer above.

@spikey_richie, For the comments that have mentioned the inactive user, it's okay to persist them. In these comments, the @mention may become an invalid user identity link after deleting the inactive user, however it generally will not affect other users to work on the objects (work items, pull requests, etc..) that contains these comments.
